# How to write a create statement using Division in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a table where I also want to use a division in it

```
create table
(
i int,
j int,
i/j as k int
)
```

I expect whenever `i` and `j` values are written it should calculate `k` also and gives the result. I know it can be done using SP or FN. Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, Computed Columns are a thing. The table definition would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    i int,
    j int,
    k AS i / j
    )
```

Your final decision is whether to make the value `PERSISTED`. A persisted field performs the calculation once on any update, and saves the value to the table, whereas a non-persisted field performs the calculation dynamically any time that the field is selected. The biggest advantage to a persisted column is that it can be used in an index - a non-persisted Computed Column can not be used in an index.